# How to test app with IPV6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipv6

I've a problem with IPV6.

**Apple reject my app with error:**

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and
>   iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, your app stayed static at the launch screen and there
>   was no further content loaded.
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

I'm try to follow: [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)
But my mac is not working with iphone 4s. Please help me another solution for test app ipv6? thank you for any help!

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. You should edit your existing question instead.

Comment: but this question i want to ask another way to connect ipv6! Thanks you so much!